# How to form redirect or rewrite where query string contains portion I want to extract to new query string

Tags: htaccess, redirects, query-string

I've transferred an old custom-made site to Mediawiki and I have many internal and external links to my old pages that I want to redirect to the appropriate wiki page.

There are many links to the old site of the form:

```
https://www.example.com/?productOrPublisher=XXXXXX
```

with the wiki, the relevant page would be

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?title=XXXXXX
```

With all the attempts below, the URL remains as
`https://www.example.com/?productOrPublisher=XXXXXX` and the front page of the site always renders.

I've tried

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^\?productOrPublisher=(.*?)$" "https://www.example.com/index.php?title=$1"
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^\?productOrPublisher=(.*) https://www.example/index.php?title=$1 [L,R=permanent]
```

but these don't work. I'm not surprised, because I think I have to be extracting from
`%{QUERY_STRING}` somehow, but I don't know how.

I tried to adapt information from the 'Rewrite query string' section of https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html for example this:

```
(.*(?:^|&))?productOrPublisher=(.*?)$
```

replacing with

```
index.php?title=$2
```

I tested this in notepad++ and there I can't get rid of the `?` after the `/`
so I get `https://www.example.com/?index.php?title=FreeMind` and I tried it in `.htaccess` but it leaves the URL unchanged.

There are many other redirects in `.htaccess` and have placed these attempts near the top after `RewriteEngine On`   and   `RewriteBase /`  to try to pre-empt others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think I have to be extracting from `%{QUERY_STRING}` somehow

Yes, you need to use mod_rewrite and check against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable in a `RewriteCond` (condition) directive.

And yes, these will need to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file (without seeing your existing `.htaccess`) to be sure there are no conflicts.

Try something like the following instead:

(I've assumed you are using Apache 2.4, as opposed to 2.2)

```
RewrietCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^productOrPublisher=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?title=%1 [R=302,L]
```

This matches a URL of the form `/?productOrPublisher=XXXXXX` (where `XXXXXX` is variable) and redirects to `/index.php?title=XXXXXX`.

It won't match if there is a URL-path, or if there are any other URL parameters before this in the query string.

`%1` is backreference to the last matched group in the preceding *CondPattern*.

This is also a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change it to a 301 (permanent) redirect when you are sure it's working OK, since 301s are cached aggressively by the browser and so can make testing problematic.

Comment: Confirmation that this works, thank you.  It won't show my upvote as rep<15, but your help much appreciated.  Been struggling for a couple of hours with this.  Note to self: Must master backreference in RegEx.